# Match code of concatenated strings with regex

Tags: regex, grep, string-concatenation

I need a regex which matches code fragments like:

`'Lo'.'re'.'m'.' Ipsum'.' dol'.'or'`

I've no idea how to even start. How would I do that if I know that the final string is
`Lorem ipsum dolor` but I don't know the positions or the amount of `'.'`?

I'm trying to find this string in some source files with `grep` over the command line.
In the code it can for example look like.

```
$random = 'Lo'.'re'.'m'.' Ipsum'.' dol'.'or';
```

Comment: Are the quotes literally part of the input?

Comment: Elaborate on your question please. What is the language/regex engine you're using? What is part of the string and what's not? All the quotes and the periods need to be removed?

Comment: Okay I'll add that, one moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tr`:

```
s="'Lo'.'re'.'m'.' Ipsum'.' dol'.'or'"
echo "$s" | tr -d "[.']"
Lorem Ipsum dolor
```

To validate with grep:

```
echo "$s" | tr -d "[.']" | grep -q 'Lorem Ipsum dolor'
echo $?
0
```

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. Now I would have to get the file contents into the first command or am I wrong? How would I do this?

Comment: Just change it to `tr -d "[.']" < FILENAME | grep -q 'Lorem Ipsum dolor'`

Comment: @MarcelGwerder: As `Ulugbek` commented you just need `tr -d "[.']" < file | grep -q 'Lorem Ipsum dolor'` command.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all not letter/space characters with nothing (delete them):

You haven't said what language you're using, so all I can do is provide the search and replace terms:

```
Search: "['.]"
Replace: "" (nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do some crazy stuff like making optional `'.'` after each letter.

```
L(?:'\.')?o(?:'\.')?r(?:'\.')?e(?:'\.')?m(?:'\.')? (?:'\.')?I(?:'\.')?p(?:'\.')?s(?:'\.')?u(?:'\.')?m(?:'\.')? (?:'\.')?d(?:'\.')?o(?:'\.')?l(?:'\.')?o(?:'\.')?r
```